# can't delete directories with rm -rf

Tags: git, unix

I trying to delete a directory called `dinkelsbuhllectura` with several subdirectories.

I'using the following command:

```
$ rm -rf dinkelsbuhllectura/
```

but instead of working I get a bunch of messages telling me that certain subdirectories are not empty. But I already know this that why I'm using the -rf options.

The errors look like this:

```
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/objects/23: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/objects/21: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/objects/da: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/objects/e6: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/objects/e8: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/objects/33: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/objects: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/hooks: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/info: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/logs/refs/remotes: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/logs/refs/heads: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/logs/refs: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/logs: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/refs/remotes/origin: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/refs/remotes: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/refs/heads: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git/refs: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5/.git: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q5: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/objects/a4: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/objects/99: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/objects/4e: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/objects/08: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/objects/23: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/objects/e6: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/objects: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/hooks: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/info: Directory not empty
rm: dinkelsbuhllectura//nddm-l4d1p2q4/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: Directory not empty
```

*Edit* Further note:

If I try to delete this in Finder it says:

`The operation can’t be completed because the item “23” is in use.`

Thank you.

Comment: execute it with `sudo`. i've experienced a similar situation, and usually it's because of permission issues.. in my case - root had checked out the github repo, so all content under `.git` was owned by root

Comment: yes. file permissions for dinkelsbuhllectura look like                                   `drwx------  1 JCWitt  staff  2048 Oct 19 12:26 dinkelsbuhllectura`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of my above.
Its an issue with mac and for some reason some program "capture" your file.

Try to login and logout it should resolve it.
Here is some more info about it:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3987969?tstart=0

> When programs open a file they put a file sysytem lock on it to prevent other programs from editing the file at the same time.
>
> This is usually a quick lock so the file can be read into memory, and then the lock is released; however, there are times when a program needs to maintain a lock, or times when a bug might prevent the lock from being released.
>
> When this happens if you try to edit or delete the file the system will not allow it and will issue you the "in use" error.
>
> **Fixing this requires quitting and relaunching of the application,** but if you cannot figure out which application it is (or if it is a background service in OS X), **then reboot the system.**
>
> This will cause all processes in OS X to release their file system locks and re-initialize, and therefore clear the problem.

Answer (score -1):

When I hit this problem, I use the following application: '[What's keeping me](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/products/wkm/wkm.html)' to figure out which application has got a lock on a file.

It has never failed me thus far (OSX 10.8) and has always allowed me to unlock files by figuring out the culprit application.

If that doesn't work, you can always go the logout-login way.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted?